# Why are my PHP files showing as plain text?

Tags: php, apache

I've been writing PHP applications using PHP for a while in WAMP. Now I'm installing PHP and Apache HTTP Server separately on my work PC. I've installed PHP 5, and the latest Apache. I go to localhost and see it works!

Now I add a file called `test.php` which displays:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

But in the browser it just displays plain text. Is there somewhere I have explicitly tell it to use PHP 5?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You'll need to add this to your server configuration:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

That is assuming you have installed PHP properly, which may not be the case since it doesn't work where it normally would immediately after installing.

It is entirely possible that you'll also have to add the `php` .so/.dll file to your Apache configuration using a `LoadModule` directive (usually in `httpd.conf`).

Comment: iamjonesy may also need to add a LoadModule command for php5_module.

Comment: This is exactly what I need to eventually make php on mac osx 10.10 yosemite work. Thx a lot :-)

Comment: In a particular case where we downloaded a client's .htaccess file, there was an extra (and incorrect) instantiation directive "AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php", which works for their old server configuration, but not ours. Once we commented this line out in .htaccess file for this site, PHP worked fine again. :-)

Comment: This posts states that AddType should be text/html and addHandler should be application/x-httpd-php, which sounds reasonable.
(https://serverfault.com/questions/394250/apache-configurations-for-php-addtype-text-html-php-or-addtype-application-x)
What's correct?

Comment: @user2345998: Seems to me now that AddHandler would be semantically more "correct". Back in 2010, this is what worked for me and many others in whatever apache version we all had running. Clearly, the answer you linked references infinitely more documentation though, I consider it better than mine here.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for your reply. Maybe you should update the answer - with apache 2.4 this doesn't work for me and caused the browser to download the parsed php file.

Comment: None of this, no variation of any of this on this or the link page, makes a bit of difference on my machine. PHP = text files, no matter what handlers or modules or anything else.

Comment: @JohnSmith: we'd need a heck of a lot more info than that to help you... Starting with what platform you are on and how did you install php?

Answer (score 105):

You should install the PHP 5 library for Apache.

**For Debian and Ubuntu:**

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

And restart the Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: for php7 apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0

Comment: libapache2-mod-php will install libapache2-mod-php7.0. We don't need to specify the version explicitly for php7

Comment: There is also now apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2 for those with 7.2.3

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php* for php7 kinda versions to auto install without the 5 specifically

Comment: for php 7.4:  apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4

Comment: @gray how about centos `yum`?

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel, how about centos `yum`?

Comment: Macports has nothing like this.

Answer (score 16):

Yet another reason (not for this case, but maybe it'll save some nerves for someone) is that in PHP 5.5 short open tags `<? phpinfo(); ?>` are disabled by default.

So the PHP interpreter would process code within short tags as plain text. In previous versions PHP this feature was enable by default. So the new behaviour can be a little bit mysterious.

Comment: To clarify, a "short open tag" is `<?`. Instead, you can replace this with `<?php`, if you don't want to change the default configuration. A closing tag is apparently no longer needed then. Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: This solved my problem after upgrading PHP from version 7.1 to 7.4. I had the short tags in a script, changed to the full php tags and it solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You need to configure Apache (the webserver) to process PHP scripts as PHP. Check Apache's configuration. You need to load the module (the path may differ on your system):

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache.dll"
```

And you also need to tell Apache what to process with PHP:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

[See the documentation for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.apache2).

Comment: thanks for your reply. The php5apache.dll file does not exist in my PHP directory. Is it always called php5apache?

Comment: The `.dll` file is called `php5apache2_2.dll` for Apache 2.2 and `php5apache2_4.dll` for Apache 2.4

Answer (score 9):

You might also, like me, have installed php-cgi prior to installing Apache and when doing so it doesn't set up Apache properly to run PHP, removing PHP entirely and reinstalling seemed to fix my problem.

Comment: I also disagree with @JaroslavKadlec, I installed out of order and removing and reinstalling did the trick for me

Answer (score 6):

You will need to add handlers in Apache to handle php code.

Edit by command sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Add these two handlers

```
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
```

at position specified below

```
<IfModule mime_module>

 AddType application/x-compress .Z
 AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

--Add Here--


</IfModule>
```

for more details on AddType handlers

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the userdir mod?

In that case the thing is that PHP5 seems to be disabling running scripts from that location by default and you have to comment out the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf` (on a ubuntu system)

Comment: Brand spanking new Ubuntu 18 install w apache2, and nowhere else did I see this mentioned!  Can I send you a pizza?  croth you-know-what-goes-after-a-name the dance dot net (no spaces).