# phpinfo() is not working on my CentOS server

Tags: centos, php

I have PHP installed on my CentOS server. However, when running a phpinfo() inside my script to test it, I receive the HTML, not the interpreted information.

I can see the folders for PHP. I can even see the php.ini in the `etc` folder.
But PHP itself does not seem to be working.

I mean my test.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

And the response looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}
body, td, th, h1, h2 {font-family: sans-serif;}
pre {margin: 0px; font-family: monospace;}
a:link {color: #000099; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ffffff;}
...
```

and so on.

What seems to be the problem and how do I solve it?

If I copy the HTML returned, paste it into an HTML file, and run it from there, I can see the formatted result, but not by running the test.php. I assume PHP is not loaded somehow... even if in the interpreted HTML I can see the:

```
**Server API    Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support    disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files    /etc/php.d
additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php.d/dbase.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
PHP API    20041225
PHP Extension    20050922
Zend Extension    220051025
Debug Build    no
Thread Safety    disabled
Zend Memory Manager    enabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams    php, file, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, compress.zlib, https, ftps**
```

and so on...

On this system, there are three websites hosted. Does that have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: It sounds like PHP is running, and `phpinfo()` is outputting the right result.  You just might have some templates or something getting in the way and throwing off the result.

Comment: That HTML code you're seeing is the same thing i see when i "view source" on a page that has nothing but `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it.  It's the HTML header of the PHP info page.

Comment: Yes. It's the HTML code that is returned normally on a normal phpinfo return page. But it is not interpreted. I see it without clicking "view source". What should I do?

Comment: If I remember correctly, php outputs HTML when doing a phpinfo() from inside a script running on a web server. Try this from the command line: php -i or run your script from the command line.

Comment: I did run php -i from the commandline, and I received a lot of text. Seems like what phpini() should return. However, since it's not working from the browser, I tend to believe there is something wrong somewhere. As I stated before, I know I have php installed, but it does not seem to be working properly.

Comment: Is there any code that runs before yours?  Like maybe a front controller / router, or something set in `auto_prepend_file`?

Comment: Had a similar issue,  (except when I opened the html page it would comment out the php code).  Changing the file name from index.html to index.php fixed it.   Using apache2 and php7.0

Answer (score 23):

This happened to me as well. The fix was wrapping it in HTML tags. Then I saved the file as **/var/www/html/info.php** and ran http://localhost/info.php in the browser. That's it.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            phpinfo();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using phpinfo(); won't display info at all. To print the configuration info's you need to echo it. So the code will be <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: I hit this after upgrading to OSX High Sierra [and php 7].

Comment: @AnbuselvanRocky is wrong. phpinfo() returns a bool. it outputs the info.  if you want to capture its info use output buffering. phpinfo returns false on failure and true on success.

Answer (score 13):

Save the page which contains

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

with the .php extension. Something like `info.php`, not `info.html`...

Comment: yup. As I stated above : `...I mean my test.php file looks like this:

<?php
phpinfo();
?>`  so, I think it's obvious, my file name is test.php

Comment: Herp. I was saving into an `.html` file, not a `.php` file. Check your extensions yo!

Answer (score 10):

You need to update your Apache configuration to make sure it's outputting `php` as the type text/HTML.

The below code should work, but some configurations are different.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: where should I run this code? Or should I add these lines to a config file?

Comment: You can add it to a .htaccess file or your main Apache config

Comment: I added the code to the httpd.conf file, restarted the httpd but nothing changed

Comment: nice! AddType was the final piece for me.

Answer (score 8):

This did it for me (the second answer): *[Why are my PHP files showing as plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text)*

Simply adding this, nothing else worked.

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: Mine couldn't find `php5` so I used `php7.0` instead: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0`. I'm running Linux Mint 18

Comment: apt-get install libapache2-mod-php will be also enough

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and found that a client had disabled this function from their `php.ini` file:

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
disable_functions = phpinfo;
```

More information: [Enabling and disabling phpinfo() for security reasons](https://www.drupal.org/node/243993)

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that the tag "php" is stick in the code like this:

**?php** phpinfo(); ?>

**Not like** this:

**? php** phpinfo(); ?>

**OR the server will treat it as a (normal word),
so the server will not understand the language you are writing to deal with it so it will be blank**.

I know it's a silly error ...but it happened ^_^

Comment: After pulling my hair out like mad, this was the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a `php.ini` file in root and write the following command in and save it.

```
disable_functions =
```

Using this code will enable the phpinfo() function for you if it is disabled by the global PHP configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well. On a newly provisioned Red Hat Linux 7 server.

When I run a PHP page, i.e. info.php, I could see plain text PHP scripts instead of executing them.

I just installed PHP:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install php
```

And then restarted Apache HTTP Server:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who have no experience in building websites (like me) I tried a lot, only to find out that I hadn't used the `.php` extension, but the `.html` extension.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was uninstalling and installing the PHP instance (7.0 in my case) again:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

After that you will need to restart the Apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Finally, verify again in your browser with your localhost or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The solution in my case was to set **default_mimetype = "text/html"** inside the *php.ini* file.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work for you if you use `localhost/info.php`.

You may be able to found the clue from the error. Find the port number in the error message. To me it was 80. I changed address as http://localhost:80/info.php, and then it worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer for Windows 10:

The command `httpd -k restart` does **not** work on my machine somehow.

Try to use the Windows 10 **Service** to restart the relative service.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally set the wrong file permissions. After `chmod 644 phpinfo.php` the info indeed showed up as expected.