# Cannot execute php scripts in apache2 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

***I'm using apache2 with php7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04***

I made a php script with code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

When I attempt to execute this script, rather than executing it the output is the code itself.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Any assistance would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you started local server ? how you run this script ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using local server.To run the script I open the link localhost/testphp.php. The file 'testphp.php' file contains the code provided above.

Comment: Is your local server working ?  localhost or localhost:80 in your browser ?

Comment: Yes it is working.

Comment: check this I hope it helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778264/phpinfo-is-not-working

Comment: I've already seen that and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate: [Apache shows php code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: You checked all your settings? Sounds like a setting issue or you are not using a .php extension (-:

Comment: @RohanSharma [php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/5177199)

Comment: Yes, I'm using .php extension and I've already seen the question in the link above and it didn't help.