# phpinfo() not showing in test page on windows 7 with apache 2.4 and php7

Tags: windows, php

I am building a new intranet server (Windows 7) replacing an old one and have installed Apache 2.4.33 and PHP 7.2.7, The services start up just fine and I can browse html pages from the server, the phpinfo in this test page does not show any results, the IP address does work and displays the correct information.

My test page is test.php and contains

```
<?php 
echo "IP Address " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

httpd.conf extract

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll" 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

I am using the development php.ini supplied with php.

I have tried all the relevant solutions in this post [phpinfo() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778264/phpinfo-is-not-working/25658226#25658226)

How do I identify and correct the problem from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed, then redownloaded and reinstalled Apache and php. It is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the `php-mcrypt` package is missing. Try installing it, adding it to the PHP extensions & restarting Apache2.

Detailed steps are mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037418).