# Browsers cant display .php file

Tags: php, html, xampp

i am trying to display a .php file on my browser but it doesnt work

i think the problem must be on the hard disk or something

i ve used Xampp 2 years ago, did a project i had and it run smoothly

3 months ago i "updated" my pc and added a new hard disk, so now my xampp folder is in the "secondary" - old disk

so i try to rerun my old project, plus my new, and they both stuck in the .php displayment

also i m not sure if xampp updates need to be done, i still run 1.7.7

my localhost page runs good, also the "php test scripts" in the left side

here' s the code i want to display

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); if (!$connect) { die("MySQL could not connect!"); }

$DB = mysql_select_db('test');

if(!$DB) { die("MySQL could not select Database!"); }


$Name = $_POST['username']; $Pass = $_POST['password']; $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$Name' AND password='$Pass'"); $NumRows = mysql_num_rows($Query); $_SESSION['username'] = $Name; $_SESSION['password'] = $Pass;


if(empty($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['password'])) { die("Go back and login before you visit this page!"); }

if($Name && $Pass == "") { die("Please enter your Username and Password!"); }

if($Name == "") { die("Please enter your Username!" . "</br>"); }

if($Pass == "") { die("Please enter your Password!" . "</br>"); }


if($NumRows != 0) { while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)) { $Database_Name = $Row['username']; $Database_Pass = $Row['password']; } } else { die("Incorrect Username or Password!"); }

if($Name == $Database_Name && $Pass == $Database_Pass) { header("Location: redirectRegister.html"); }

?>
```

also the the code of my html file which refers to my .php file

```
<form action="users.php" method="POST" />
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

and here's what i get from all 3 browsers :

"); } if($Pass == "") { die("Please enter your Password!" . "
"); } if($NumRows != 0) { while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)) { $Database_Name = $Row['username']; $Database_Pass = $Row['password']; } } else { die("Incorrect Username or Password!"); } if($Name == $Database_Name && $Pass == $Database_Pass) { header("Location: redirectRegister.html"); } ?>

something wrong with the installation i suppose, do i need to reinstall the whole xampp program in my new disk?

will i need to recreate all my databases again?

thank you <3

-edit-

still cant fix it

i reinstalled xampp in my main disk and also reinstalled php according to a guide

it said i should copy/paste a php-recommend.ini file to the windows folder and rename it to php.ini

i didnt have any such file, i got 2 files with the names php-production and php-development, which were the same

dunno what else to do really

-edit2-

i managed to run it at last
here's the problem :

*when i run it through the folder, my .php cant be read (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/main.html)

*when i run it through localhost path, my .php runs (http://*localhost*/main.html)

any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text

Answer (score 0):

All the code is fine, so I would guess an installation issue or a problem communicating between the two drives.
This can normally by fixed with a reinstallation or checking the communication between drives by using another program.

Comment: sorry guys, still cant fix this -.-