# El Capitan pgsql extension

Tags: php, osx-elcapitan, php-pgsql

I just installed OS X El Capitan and it apparently overrode my php and pgsql settings. Can anyone walk me through install/settings to get this back up?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add the extension using homebrew.

> brew install php56-pdo-pgsql

Make sure `brew update` works because homebrew is also affected after the El Capitan update.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

uncomment the following line:

> LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Add the following line to the "mime_module" directive

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

uncomment the following line

> Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

restart apache

> sudo apachectl restart

You should be good after that

Comment: Thanks!  Getting closer!!  Now it runs my virtual hosts again, but it still reads my php files as text files.  When I do a "get" to any php file, it returns it as text.

Comment: going through the same thing, check your .pre-update files.  you will need to fix your php.ini most likely as well.  I had to reinstall a bunch of php modules.  but I still can't get postgres to work with php.....

Comment: @Dean check out this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text to help with the php as plain text