# Running phpMyAdmin in ubuntu getting different output

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation

I am using ubuntu and I have installed phpmyadmin using terminal following a tutorial.

[image]

Above image is showing the output when I access `localhost/phpmyadmin`

> How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your phpmyadmin is working like it should but your php is not. Phpmyadmin is built with php. Please check your php installation. `<php phpinfo() ?>`

[why are my php files showing as plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text)

https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/accessing-phpmyadmin-returns-php-as-text.63896/