# php file isn't working properly, I can't open it on browser, it opens the text editer instead

Tags: php, mamp, bitnami

So I'm just starting to learn php, and when trying " Hello World" the file isn't executing properly. I have Bitnami MAMP Stack 5.6.31 . 
I'm pretty sure it's not something wrong with the code, possibly with the install of the AMP stack, but this is the code anyway :

```
    <?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Comment: This is a pretty broad problem, as any number of things could be wrong, including: a misconfigured Apache server, misconfigured PHP, incorrect file permission/ownership, etc.  Without knowing the steps you've taken and how you've configured things, it's impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Check out this; [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text Might help :)

Comment: Are you double clicking on the file to open it or how are you trying to execute the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "open" PHP files on XAMPP/MAMP/LAMPP/etc.

1. Make sure your apache service is started in your MAMP console
2. Make sure your file is saved in the document root of MAMP, which by default is 'MAMP/htdocs'
3. If your file, say is stored like this: 'MAMP/htdocs/learningPHP/hello.php' then you would go to your web browser and type in localhost/learningPHP/hello.php

The script will then run.