# Problem with install Symfony 4 production server on apache2

Tags: symfony, server, production, ubuntu-19.04

I try to set up production server with symfony 4 app. I use Apache2 on Ubuntu(on VirtualBox). I use this support article:
 https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

It's empty symfony skeleton with just apache-pack

I expected see website, but i see just:

> handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request,
>   $response)

Nothing more, just text. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: Looks like mod php not installed on your Apache server

Comment: I already install `libapache2-mod-php`, what else can be problem?

Comment: Try to discover this questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text