# Why the page show a php script?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I created a PHP local site, and I don't know why but when I open my page I see only the PHP script on my google chrome page.

I created a Vhost like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.localhost
    ServerAlias site.localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/user/Bureau/www
    <Directory /home/user/Bureau/www>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myproject-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My site does not have a problem because everything worked before.

I use LAMP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my PHP files showing as plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text)

Comment: hello, i checked this booth links but i cant find the file conf "httpd.conf" to add "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php"