# Apache shows php files as plain text, except for DirectoryIndex

Tags: php, apache

I use my webserver for e.g. nextcloud.

Until now I could enter the cloud via `https://mydomain/nextcloud`.
But for some reason the nextcloud page is displayed as plain text!?

It works if I enter the index page `https://mydomain/nextcloud/index.php`.

---

Because I had no time to solve this problem yet, my workaround was:

```
yum reinstall php
systemctl restart httpd
```

But since today that does not work anymore..!?

---

Thinks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555681/why-are-my-php-files-showing-as-plain-text) did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this at the appropriate place?

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.shtml index.sht index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Is the module loaded?

If the URI points to an directory, Apache will try to append an index file.

1. It will walk the list in `DirectoryIndex` and use the first file that exists.
2. If not Apache will show the content of the folder (if allowed) or send an HTTP status code 403.

`DirectoryIndex` can be set globaly in `httpd.conf` and additionally in the `<VirtualHost ... >` container for the individual virtual host.

*Does your shown "plain text" contain PHP script code?*

As your answer is "Yes":
Your problem is that PHP is not interpreting the code.

Is PHP installed? – What's the result of this command?

```
php -v
```

As in the past php has worked I would suggest also to reinstall php:

```
yum reinstall php php-cli
```

.... plus possibly some extras that nextcloud might require.

Comment: I had only the `DirectoryIndex index.php` part.
After replacing it with your posted `IfModule dir_module ...` I was able to access my roundcube page (wich was previously broken, too) but the nextcloud folder is still inaccessible..

Comment: At _Does your shown "plain text" contain PHP script code?_: Yes it does!

Comment: Sure, php is installed. The `php -v` output is `PHP 7.4.33 (cli)`

Comment: Please note: nexcloud is ready for PHP 8 and all versions below 8.0 are not supported anymore by php.org — but this is not the problem of your current issue.

Comment: lol, that worked!
But: I had already tried `yum reinstall php*` (which included the cli). Why did that not work?!
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Na dann, viel Glück mit dem Rest :-)